# To get a specifc part of a numberin c#

Tags: c#

I have a number:

```
Int64 a = 5021390010301;
```

And I want to get like

```
Int64 b = 30;
```

I tried:

```
string b = Convert.ToString(a).Substring(0 , 12);
```

That give me `502139001030`. I also tried:

```
string b = Convert.ToString(a).Substring(11 , 12);
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: `Substring(10 , 2)`

Comment: How doesn't it work? What is the value of `string b`?

Comment: `a.ToString().Substring(11,2)`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Think, he means int64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) is the number of characters to take, not the index of the last character. So you will need something like this instead:

```
string b = Convert.ToString(a).Substring(10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Substring-Documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see that the second parameter is actually the length of the string.

If you want to get the last quarter of the string you have to write:

```
string b = convert.ToString(a).Substring(9 , 3);
```

And since you want an integer, you'll have to parse it:

```
int result = Int32.Parse(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `String.Substring` is the length not the end index and the first index is 0.

```
int b = int.Parse(a.ToString().Substring(10, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it without converting it to a string first:

```
Int64 b = a % 1000 / 10;
```

This will work as long as you don't use a float or a double.